# How to count rows fulfilling certain conditions, for at least 2 rows out of the last 7 rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I'm trying to write a rolling function where it checks "close" for 7 consecutive rows, if all of them are "hovering" around "mid", for lack of better term.

For visual reference, it looks like these candlesticks are "hovering around that middle yellow line, in the white box below. The closing values of the candlesticks makes up "close", while the values of middle yellow line makes up "mid".

[image]

Expected output

[image: Expected output]

**First part:** How I intent to define "hovering" is that there are at least 2 out of 7 rows where "close" is more than "mid", and also at least 2 out of 7 rows where "close" is less than "mid".

My dataframe runs into hundreds of rows, each row depicting a min.

I am using basic numpy to make sure all "close" are below "upper" (depicted by the top yellow line), but I'm lost how to do a "count out of 7 rows" scenario.

```
def function1(df):
#past 7 candles cannot close above upper line
no_upper_breach = np.where((df.close.shift(7) < df.upper.shift(7)) & (df.close.shift(6) < df.upper.shift(6)) & 
(df.close.shift(5) < df.upper.shift(5)) & (df.close.shift(4) < df.upper.shift(4)) & 
(df.close.shift(3) < df.upper.shift(3)) & (df.close.shift(2) < df.upper.shift(2)) & 
(df.close.shift(1) < df.upper.shift(1)), True, False)
#past 7 candles as least 2 of the past 7 candles must be under middle line
two_below_middle = ??
#past 7 candles as least 2 of the past 7 candles must be above middle line
two_above_middle = ??
df['function1'] = no_upper_breach & two_below_middle & two_above_middle
#convert TRUE/FALSE into simple one or zero
df['function1'] = df['function1'].astype(int)
return df
```

**Second part:** How do I have a new column 'function1' added to the dataframe and show either 1 or 0? 1 being all 3 conditions are true.

This is the line from the above code where I'm trying to get show True if all 3 conditions are true, False otherwise.

```
df['function1'] = no_upper_breach & two_below_middle & two_above_middle
```

Please advise!